# Regular expression is 'invalid' mongodb in python

Tags: python, regex, mongodb

I am trying to query sentences with specific keywords. I am using python btw

my implementation:

```
words = ['word1', 'word2']
#dummy set of words, words are fetched dynamically

queryList = sum([[{'title':{'$regex':w, '$options':'i'}}, {'media':{'$regex':w, '$options':'i'}}] for w in words], [])
#creating a list of all queries for passing into an $or operation
query = {'$or':queryList}
#preparing the query 

posts = (postsCollection.find(query).sort('points', -1))
```

it is returning me `Regular expression is invalid`

sometimes it doesn't give me a specific set of words and it gives an error with another particular set of words

Comment: Does it return the error with those exact values?

Comment: What are the specific `words`, i.e. `'$regex'` values that generate the error?  If you are specifically looking for keywords, have you considered creating a [text index](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/index-text/) on fields `'title'` and `'media'` and then using [`'$text`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/text/)?